# getting error !! Picker: the selection "nil" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

this is my main file getting error in picker not able to select the value from picker getting error in first picker

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View { 
    @ObservedObject private var branchSelectionViewModel = BranchSelectionViewModel() 
    @StateObject private var semesterSelectionViewModel = SemesterSelectionViewModel() 
    @StateObject private var subjectListViewModel = SubjectListViewModel() 
    @StateObject private var paperListViewModel = PaperListViewModel()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Picker("Select Branch", selection: $branchSelectionViewModel.selectedBranch) {
                    ForEach(branchSelectionViewModel.branches, id: \.id) { branch in
                        Text(branch.name).tag(branch)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
                
                
                
                Picker("Select Semester", selection: $semesterSelectionViewModel.selectedSemester) {
                    ForEach(semesterSelectionViewModel.semesters, id: \.id) { semester in
                        Text(semester.name).tag(semester)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                
                if let selectedBranch = branchSelectionViewModel.selectedBranch,
                   let selectedSemester = semesterSelectionViewModel.selectedSemester {
                    SubjectListView(viewModel: subjectListViewModel,
                                    branchId: selectedBranch.id,
                                    semesterId: selectedSemester.id)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            branchSelectionViewModel.fetchBranches()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Previous Year Papers")
    }
}
}
```

below code is the BranchSelectionViewModel from which picker is selecting the branch but in terminal getting message "Picker: the selection "nil" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results"

```
class BranchSelectionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var branches: [Branch] = []
    @Published var selectedBranch: Branch?
    
    func fetchBranches() {
        // Simulate fetching branches from a network or database
        branches = [
            Branch(id: 1, name: "Computer Science"),
            Branch(id: 2, name: "Electrical Engineering"),
            // ... add more branches ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedBranch` is an optional, it can be `nil`. But there is no corresponding tag for *Nothing selected* aka `nil`.

A possible solution is to make `selectedBranch` non-optional with a default value for example of `Branch(id: 0, name: "None")`. Append new branches to the array and restore the default value when the array becomes empty. Or use the default value only if the array is empty.

Side note:

Use **always** `@StateObject` for objects owned by the view.
`@ObservedObject` is the reference type equivalent of `@Binding`.